# How to hook fopen using Frida in Android?

Tags: hook, fopen, frida

I have an android application into which I load a library and at some point I read a file. This is the code that is being used in the app.

```
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        return res;
    }
```

Now I am attempting using [Frida](https://www.frida.re/) to hook that `fopen` in order to force it to return null but I do not seem to be able to find out how.

The library that is included in the application is called `libnative-lib.so` and my attempt in hooking `fopen` includes the following code for frida

```
 Module.enumerateExports("libnative-lib.so", {                
      onMatch: function(e) {                            
          if(e.type == 'function') {
              if(e.name == "fopen") {
        console.log("Function recognized by name");
        Interceptor.attach(e.address, {       
        onEnter: function(args) {         
            console.log("Interceptor attached onEnter...");
            },                                
        onLeave: function(retval){        
            console.log("Interceptor attached onLeave...");
            }                                 
        });                                                                   
              }                   
          }                                             
      },                                                
      onComplete: function() {}                         
  });
```

Comment: You are using the file name `libnative-lib.so` as module name - are you sure this is the correct module name? Better enumerate them and select the correct name from the list: https://github.com/poxyran/misc/blob/master/frida-enumerate-modules.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of enumerating the exports of a specific library, you can try calling `Module.findExportByName(null, "fopen")` to get the address of `fopen` (the null argument tells frida to look through the exports of all of the loaded libraries) and use the `Interceptor` API the same way you did.
This should look somewhat like this:

```
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, "fopen"), {
    onEnter: function(args) {
        console.log("Interceptor attached onEnter...");
    },
    onLeave: function(args) {
        console.log("Interceptor attached onLeave...");
    }
}
```

You haven't stated exactly how your code fails, but to make sure that the library you are talking about is actually loaded in the app, you can list all of the loaded modules:

```
Process.enumerateModules()
    .forEach(function(m) {
        // You can print just the name by using m.name or the entire system path with m.path
        console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
    });
```

Another way would be using `Process.enumerateModules()` to find the correct module and then calling `enumerateExports` on the `Module` object you got.
This will make sure you are searching for `fopen` in the correct module if the name of the module is not exactly `libnative-lib.so`:

```
Process.enumerateModules()
    .filter(function(m){ return m["path"].toLowerCase().indexOf("libnative") != -1 ; })
    .forEach(function(mod) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(mod));
        mod.enumerateExports().forEach(function (exp) {
            if (exp.name.indexOf("fopen") != -1) {
                console.log("fopen found!");
            }
        })
    });
```

HTH, if this still doesn't solve your problem post some additional information in your question.

Comment: Using the `enumerateModules` indeed i verified that the correct library named `libnative-lib.so` is loaded and it indeed has `fopen`. But when trying to use the first snippet of code you posted using `Interceptor.attach` the error coming up is `Failed to load script: gDBus.Error:re.frida.Error.InvalidArgument: Script(line 12): SyntaxError: parse error`

Comment: @kampias it's just a small syntax error in the first snippet. After closing the object in the second argument to Interceptor.attach i forgot to close the call to attach. Just add ); to the end of the snippet and it should work

Comment: i dont know how i missed that... Indeed it works now so the goal of the question if accomplished and i marked it as solved. Though, do you have any idea as to why the application crashes after hooking `fopen` using the first snippet?

Comment: I can't be sure without knowing what app you are trying to play with or at least the code you tried to execute in onEnter and onLeave. Problems can range from anything to your code creating too much of a load on the program so it crashes (if many fopens are called) to hook detection mechanisms (unlikely) to you doing something bad in your callbacks. Hard to tell without having more information

Answer (score 1):

fopen will invoke open

I would suggest use a condition to assert it opens your specific file & not to replace/override.

```js
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, "open"), {
  onEnter: function(args) {
    this.file_name = Memory.readCString(ptr(args[0]));
  },
  onLeave: function(retval) {
    if ("your file name" === this.file_name) // passed from onEnter
      retval.replace(0x0); // return null
  }
});
```

BTW, if you enable the flag `--enable-jit` you could filter with ECMAScript6

```js
Module.enumerateExports(moduleName).filter(ex => ex.name.includes('fopen')).forEach(ex => { .. })
```